# Quadcopter - is iPhone the ultimate flight controller?

Tags: quadcopter

iPhone contains

- Gyroscope
- GPS
- Two photo and video cameras
- Self-sufficient battery that outlives the motor battery
- Wifi
- Backup connectivity (cellular, bluetooth)
- Programmable computer
- Real-time image processing capabilities and face detection
- General purpose IO (with something like [this](http://redpark.com/lightning-serial-cable-l2-db9v/))

and old models are available very cheap.

What is the main benefit of having a separate dedicated flight controller and camera on hobbyist rotorcraft rather than a general purpose device like the iPhone?

Comment: The iPhone's sensors may be plentiful, but they're nothing to write home about. Look at the iPhone 5 as an example - https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+5+Teardown/10525. It uses the L3G4200D Gyro - http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/04/46/d6/00/be/d9/46/ae/CD00265057.pdf/files/CD00265057.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00265057.pdf, which is inferior to the type used in the Naze32 Acro flight controller (cheaper than an iPhone) - http://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/mpu-6500/. And the list goes on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking from experience, smartphones (android in my case) do work as flight controllers but they have significant drawbacks

- The operating system gets in the way. You don't have root access and can't kill off unnecessary processes.
- The cameras are decent, but somewhat narrow field-of-view. Dual cameras  are not setup to enable stereo vision and even trying to use both at the same time overheats the phone quickly.
- Camera placement is fixed relative to the body (problem if you want to look forward rather than down)
- IMU sensors are really cheap which leads to noisy signals
- Everything is thermally connected and not well cooled, so sensors exhibit significant drift.
- You still need extra processors. Most motors talk over PWM or i2c so you need a board to receive commands from the phone and translate.
- WIFI range is smaller than most RC transmitter/receiver pairs.

Like I said, you can make it work but it is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Using a smart-phone may have advantages, but anything that can be accomplished using other traditional flight controllers.

**Some advantages**

- Easier to implement
- Relatively cheap
- Relatively user-friendly
- Usually a built in way to recover the craft in the event of a flyaway (caused by what is doing the flight controls)

**Some disadvantages**

- Limited to the operating system's abilities and quarks
- Without rooting the device you may not be able to kill a process that is not responding
- Not as customizable as using an opens-ource flight controller
- latency caused by running a full operating system
- Smart-phones are fragile and ca

  [Here](http://oddcopter.com/flight-controllers/) is a list of common flight controllers and their capabilities.